No stdout output from logging after SIGINT
I have a ROS2 Python setup:

Top launch file start_robot_launch that includes launch files for all the other submodules and nodes
Several nodes handling different responsibilities, one manager_node handling transitions for the whole system
All nodes ignore SIGINT
start_robot_launch has a custom handler that invokes the transition in the manager_node

My launch file (simplified):
class LifecycleTransitionShutdownHandler(EventHandler):
    def __init__(self, node_name, transition_id):
        super().__init__(matcher=lambda event: isinstance(event, Shutdown))
        self.node_name = node_name
        self.transition_id = transition_id

    def handle(self, event, context):
        rclpy.init(args=None)
        node = rclpy.create_node('lifecycle_manager_shutdown')
        client = node.create_client(
                    ChangeState,
                    f"/{self.node_name}/change_state",
                )

        if not client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=10.0):
            node.get_logger().error(f'Service {self.node_name}/change_state not available')
            rclpy.shutdown()
            return

        request = ChangeState.Request()
        request.transition.id = self.transition_id

        future = client.call_async(request)
        node.get_logger().info(f'Sending request to {self.node_name} to shut down')
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(node, future)

        if future.result().success:
            node.get_logger().info(f'Successfully shutted down {self.node_name}')
        else:
            node.get_logger().error(f'Failed to shut down {self.node_name}')
        
        node.destroy_node()

def generate_launch_description():
    # define all the arguments

    # include all the launch files

    manager = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [
                    FindPackageShare("sitetech_lifecycle"),
                    "launch",
                    "manager.launch.py",
                ]
            )
        ),
        launch_arguments=[
            {"dry-run", simulating},
            {"manager-config-type", config_type},
        ],
    )

    shutdown_event = RegisterEventHandler(
        LifecycleTransitionShutdownHandler(
            node_name=ids.MANAGER_NODE,
            transition_id=Transition.TRANSITION_ACTIVE_SHUTDOWN
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            # arguments
            # launch files
            manager,
            shutdown_event
        ]
    )

The problem:

On CTRL+C the shutting down works as intended, on_shutdown methods are called in all the nodes at the right time
The on_shutdown methods in my nodes contain logging
These logs are sent to rosout (checked through rqt)
But they are never printed to the console!
The only logs printed to console are from the temporary lifecycle_manager_shutdown node created in the handler

Extra info:

I tried flushing the loggers. Didn't help.
Logging works fine in on_activate and other parts of the program up until CTRL+C
If an exception is thrown during the shutdown it is logged in the console and then all the previously unseen logs appear (!)

So my bet is that SIGINT somehow shuts down the rclutils layer responsible for logging into the console right away and therefore logs sent after that are not written in it. The temporary node logs are displayed because it invokes the rclpy.init, create_node etc afterward.
Is it the probable cause? And how to ensure all logs from rosout are written to the console up to the very end of the run?
